# Set specific dates

Tags: datetime, date

I have spent a fair couple of hours on this, including searching this forum, but I still haven't managed to solve my issue, therefore decided to ask a question here.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
\newcommand{\NewDocDate}{\today}
\newcommand{\PrevVersion}{\date}{06}{09}{2020}
```

And later in the doc, I call NewDocDate and PrevVersion. While the NewDocDate returns the correct date, the PrevVersion returns empty space. I have also tried using the following variations:

```
\newcommand{\PrevVersion}{date}{06}{09}{2020}
```

Which returned "date" when called. I also tried:

```
\newcommand{\PrevVersion}{\date}{06 June 2020}
```

Which returned empty space again.

I am using the package datetime using the command:

```
\usepackage{datetime}
```

PS: I am a noob...what am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for your time & help.

Comment: You need to add a backslash in front of the name of your new command, e.g. `\newcommand{\NewDocDate}{\today}`. `\PrevVersion` probably needs further adjustments. What do you expect `\PrevVersion` to do?

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo, I do have the backslash in front of the \PrevVersion and \NewDocDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SE!

Here my solution that I think solves your issue:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{datetime}

\newcommand{\NewDocDate}{\today}
\newdate{PrevVersionDate}{06}{09}{2020}%define date
\newcommand{\PrevVersion}{\displaydate{PrevVersionDate}}%assigne afformentioned date to a newcommand

\begin{document}

\NewDocDate

\PrevVersion

\end{document}
```

For the Future please post a complete minimal working example (MWE) that shows your problem (as I posted a MWE that solves the issue) as we don't have to guess which `documentclass` and maybe even other packages that might interfere with your problem you are using.

Screenshot of my Output:
[image]
I haven't applied any formatting to the output yet.

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot? This would be helpful, especially because the desired output is not yet clear.

Comment: @user187803 please see my edited answer.

Comment: This has solved my problem, and I would have never figured this out by myself: so I would like to thank you for helping me save potentially hours of painful trial & error. PS: you have a "typo", i.e. "PrevVe**s**rion" instead of "PrevVersion", could potentially cause issues for someone copy-pasting your code :)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I corrected the typo!

Sometimes it can be helpful to read/search the documentation of the respective package, e.g. over on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/), in this case the documentation can be found [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime).

Comment: Appreciate your help, Lukas, thank you so much. Have a great weekend.